# Data is not coming to Annotation method in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, callout

How to send the data  to

```
 -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:
    (id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
```

method. Once please observe my code and give  me the solution.

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation: (id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";

    MKAnnotationView *pinView =(MKAnnotationView *)[mapview dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
    NSLog(@"pinData....%@",pinView);
    if (pinView == nil){
        pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];

        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.enabled = YES;

        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [pinView setSelected:YES animated:YES];

        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"location.png"];
    }
    else{

    }

    return  pinView;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "How to send the data to"? It's a delegate method and you can access any properties you need from this method...

Answer (score 0):

If you add an annotation to your map and set the class that contains the code you showed above as the map's delegate, then iOS will call `viewForAnnotation` when ever it needs to redraw it